# FileSystemWatcher Filter Hiccups

Tags: c#

I'm trying to set up a FileSystemWatcher to monitor a path that could contain a few varieties of file names and extension, only some of which I care about.  I know I need to use a Filter, but am having an issue.

The files that are in the directory will be named something like:

File_Current.txt,   File_00.txt,   File_01.txt,   etc...

What I want to Filter on is all files that have a .txt extension with a number preceding it. The _Current files I would like to ignore completely.

This sounds like a use for some RegEx magic, but as a novice, I have yet to wrap my mind around this...  Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible using the built in functionality. The best you can do is from [this article](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/113118-howto-regex-filesystemwatcher-filter), and filter *.txt and then run a regex on the incoming values.

The regex to filter only #.txt would be something like this `.*[\d.]+\.txt`. Or you could filter out the current files with `.*Current\.txt`